# Sitecore multiple CD web databases publishing/indexing EventQueue database name

Tags: publishing, indexing, events, content-delivery, event-queue

Say I have a single CM with 1x master db, 1x core db and 2x web dbs (2x publishing targets) for 2x CD servers in different regions. I can't call both web dbs "web" - one must be something different, e.g. "web2".

```
-----------------            / CD1 ("web")
|       CM       |--------- <
| ("web","web2") |           \ CD2 ("web2" but locally called "web")
-----------------
```

On CD1, it only sees its own web db called "web". It doesn't know anything about "web2".

On CD2, I want the config to be the same, so it only knows about its own web db called "web".

Will this cause problems with the `EventQueue` and publishing/indexing operations? In other words, will the CM put events into the `EventQueue` tagged against "web" and "web2" respectively, meaning that CD2 won't respond to events for "web2" because it doesn't know what "web2" is?

### Do I need to transform the config on CD2 so that its "web" db is actually referred to as "web2" everywhere?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97753/discussion-on-question-by-theyetiman-sitecore-multiple-cd-web-databases-publishi).

Answer (score -2):

It requires to enable scalability settings config with unique instance name in each server and publishing instance name as CMS name. Once it is setup then it will work as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I already have scalability settings enabled. Each server has a unique instance name, but the name of the web database is not related to the instance name unless I've misunderstood something?